# Another way to use <%# Bind %>

Tags: asp.net, listview, data-binding

I am trying to use the Bind Property <%# Bind %> however I am joining many tables and I am unable to use the column with the name c.FormID because of the dot. When debugging it only sees it as "c".

Is there a way to get around this?

My code:

```
SelectedValue='<%# Bind("c.FormID") %>'
```

Heres my sql code:

```
SELECT c.FormID, FormSectionSubSectionItemRelID,c.ControlTypeID,c.FormSectionID,c.SubSectionID,c.SectionItemID,c.ValidationRulesetId,c.CrossItemID, FormTitle, FormSection ,SubSection, SectionItem, SortOrder, SectionSortOrder,SubSectionSortOrder, RulesetDesc,ControlType, CrossItem  FROM Core. Form_Section_SubSection_Item_Rel c
FULL OUTER JOIN Core.FormSection_Lkup l
ON c.FormSectionID = l.FormSectionID FULL OUTER JOIN Core.FormSubSection_Lkup s
ON c.SubSectionID = s.SubSectionID FULL OUTER JOIN Core.SectionItem_Lkup i
ON c.SectionItemID = i.SectionItemID FULL OUTER JOIN Core.Form_Lkup f
ON c.FormID = f.FormID FULL OUTER JOIN Core.ValidationRuleset v
ON c.ValidationRulesetId = v.ValidationRulesetId FULL OUTER JOIN Core.ControlType_Lkup  t
ON c.ControlTypeID = t.ControlTypeID FULL OUTER JOIN Core.CrossItem_Lkup g
ON c.CrossItemID = g.CrossItemID  WHERE [DataCollectionPeriodID] = 74 ORDER BY FormTitle,FormSection
```

Comment: I don't think `Bind` can infer the relationship between your joined tables. Rather give a alias name for `c.FormID` as `cFormID` in the select statement of the datasource and use the alias name in the binding.

Comment: @DennisR tried it but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give a alias name for `c.FormID` as `FormID` in the select statement and use the alias name in the binding. Change the below statement

```
SELECT c.FormID, FormSectionSubSectionItemRelID, ...
```

to

```
SELECT c.FormID as FormID, FormSectionSubSectionItemRelID, ....
```

and then refer `FormID` in the binding

```
SelectedValue='<%# Bind("FormID") %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

The column's name is FormID, the c.FormID is just telling the statement to use table c, not actually naming the column "c.FormID"

Comment: I understand but it doesn't allow me to use just FormID either